# Formal equation for variance retention in PCA

Tags: self-study, variance, pca, dimensionality-reduction

In [lecture 8](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/exam/B20Bx/principal-component-analysis) of his Coursera machine learning course Andrew Ng states that $$\frac{ \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m {|| x^{(i)}-{x^{(i)}_{\text {approx}}} ||}^2}{\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m {|| x^{(i)} ||}^2}\le 0.05$$

means "95 % of the variance was retained". Can anyone explain to me why the equation means that?

---

I understand that you can reduce $\frac{1}{m}$ in the equation, but afterwards I have no idea.

#### Edit:

Agenda:

$x^{(i)}$: Original data points of the variables before the Principal Component Analysis

$x^{(i)}_{approx}$: The data points after the principal component analysis

The numerator as a whole stands for the "Average squared projection error".
The denominator as a whole stands for the "Total Variation of the data".
So you can also rephrase the equation as

$$\frac{\text{Average squared projection error}}{\text{Total variation of the data}}\le 0.05$$

Edit: You can also have a look at [Slide 24](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_a5935af6cf0625a072cb6e2962e4a47f_Lecture14.pdf?Expires=1506816000&Signature=ZNP5qEWEcuHPyvLyuBMTmqeXfrYIAcKzz5llJDFR4ggSmpL1FurWhNyXT-wVObA5kpB2YGr4ks0W0Ks1gE3dh2Mr5Mx6QAUUkiUJOWghizN3yc6udVol%7ERdKu1LADaigUzDG50Y3Os80Qb%7EbrIdVyE4D-mj6GCcqmT-dMbxUC9I_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) of this Powerpoint presentation:

[image: Slide 24]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x_1, \ldots x_n$ are n observations, we can think of $X = (x_1, \ldots x_n) \in R^n $ and assuming the mean of X is zero, then $Var(x) = ||x||$ . That is the Euclidean distance, || ||, '*is* variance.  If $x_1$ is another variable, the $||x - x_1|| $ is 'the variance of x not explained by $x_1$ and $\frac{||x - x_1||}{||x||} $ is the percentage of the variance of x not explained by $x_1$.    If one has m variables, $ 1 \leq i \leq m$  then the same remains true for $x^i $.  The the observations and the approximate observations are points in some Euclidean space with norm (distance) || || and the numerator of the equation is the average distance from x to the  $x^i$ , that is the average variance of x not explained by the $x^i$ and similarly for the denominator.

Comment: Andrew Ng uses $x^{(i)}$ to denote $i$-th observation, not $i$-th variable. It seems that you use the opposite notation, and this can create quite some confusion.